# Ideal sheaf that defines singular locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking for a scheme theoretic definition of the singular locus of a variety over a field $K$ of characteristic zero that carries not only the information of which points are singular, but also in some suitable sense how singular these points are.

If we have an affine (irreducible) $K$-variety $X$ of dimendion $d$, we can write it as the spectrum of a finitely generated $K$-algebra $A=K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_1,\ldots, f_r)$. Then the singular locus of $X$ is cut out by the ideal $I$ of $A$ generated by the $(n-d) \times (n-d)$ minors of the Jacobian matrix $J=(\partial f_i / \partial x_j)$. Thus we can define the singular locus of $X$ to be the closed subscheme $\textrm{Spec} A/I$ which is not necessarily reduced. Perhaps for an arbitrary variety one can cover by open affines and do this construction locally.

So these are my questions:

1. Is this the common way to define the singular locus of a variety as a subscheme?
2. This construction seems to be a bit cumbersome since we first have to choose an embedding to some affine space and also it is not immediately that it does not depend on the choice of the embedding. Is there a better, more intrinsic definition?

EDIT: If this question is too difficult or not known in general, then I would already find an answer that only addresses the case of curves helpful.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but my feeling is that if you could make this work intrinsically then you wouldn't see people take the reduced induced structure on $X_{\text{sing}}$ so often and you wouldn't have to bother with multiplier ideals and stuff like that. But let's see!